# How to programmatically extract SAML token for IDP and SP?

Tags: saml, adfs

I have SSO configured between IDP (ADFS) and SP, and IDP generate SAML token and post to the SP page for authentication. But, I like to create a new application called test-app, and this app should programmatically generate/extract SAML token for IDP and SP by using a pop up login window.

Is it possible?

After I get the SAML token, I intent to use it on a REST webservice of the SP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SAML flow requires the SAML token to be generated by the IDP.

The IDP has the private key to sign the SAML token.

You can generate one in your app. but you won't be able to sign it correctly and there is no flow to send it to the IDP.